# Property of parallelograms

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Is there a **theorem** saying that:

> If in a parallelogram $ABCD$ the diagonals intersect at $O$, $O$ bisects every segment with ends, lying on $AB$ and $CD$.

I noticed this and I was wondering if I can use it without showing. How can I prove it?

[image: diagonals_of_a_parallelogram]

$\triangle AON \cong MOD$.

Comment: How are **you** going to prove it? Any ideas/attempt?

Comment: You need to convince us that you've attempted to solve the problem. Add a summary of what you have tried/thought (no matter how meaningless it may seem to you) in the question body.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri, Edited. I am just looking for different solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prove this by rotation. Rotate the drawing by half a revolution about the center $O$. Any rotation preserves angles and lengths. Thus $\angle AON$ gets mapped to $\angle DOM$, and $\angle OAB$ gets mapped to $\angle ODC$. Now $\triangle AON$ gets mapped to $\triangle DOM$ which are congruent using ASA congruence since $\overline {DO} \cong \overline {AO}$ . Now $\overline {MO} \cong \overline {NO}$ are congruent because the triangles are congruent. This implies that $O$ bisects $\overline {MN}$.

Comment: I don't see why rotation is required at all?

Comment: @ShubhamJohri On a logical level, rotation is **not** required, but I used rotation to visualize what the relations were between the parts of the drawing. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Consider $\triangle OBF$ and $\triangle ODE$. $$OB=OD\\\angle EOD=\angle FOB\\\angle OBF=\angle ODE$$Thus, $\triangle OBF\cong\triangle ODE$. Congruent parts of congruent triangles are equal, which gives you $OF=OE$.

---

[image]

Alternatively, note that $\text{ar}(\triangle AOB)=\text{ar}(\triangle COD)$, a straight-forward consequence of Heron's formula.

$\text{ar}(\triangle AOB)=\frac12AB\times OF'=\frac12AB\times OF\times\cos\angle FOF'\\\text{ar}(\triangle COD)=\frac12CD\times OE'=\frac12AB\times OE\times\cos\angle FOF'$

Comment: Same as mine. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @Valeri  You have not actually stated your attempt at a proof.  How do you expect somebody to come up with a different proof without knowing what your proof was?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, just look at the post again. Maybe you'll see it.

Comment: @Valeri I understand the proof.  However, you have not stated the reasoning behind your assertions, nor have you marked the vertical angles congruent.

Comment: @Valeri See the edited answer.